# How to find the length of an indefinitely repeated sequence in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence

Here, I am not looking for simply a repeated element, but an indefinitely repeated sequence. For example, if I have the list

```
{1,3,4,3,4,2,3,3,2,3,3,2,3,3,2,3,3,2,3,3}
```

I would like Mathematica to output $3$, since the sequence $(2,3,3)$ (with length 3) repeats until the end of the sequence after a certain point. Note, the repeated sequence needs to continue until the end of the list. For example, the sequence $(3,4)$ does repeat itself near the beginning of the list, however I would not want an output of $2$ due to this repetition since the sequence $(3,4)$ does not continue after a certain point.

More formally: If I input a list for which the $i^{th}$ element is $x_i$, I want Mathematica to output the smallest number $n$ for which $x_i=x_{i+n}$ for all sufficiently large $i$.

What function/code would allow me to input a list and then would output the desired result?

Comment: duplicate?: [Find cycle length in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175338/125)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this?:

```
Length@Last@FindTransientRepeat[
   {1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3}, 2]
(*  3  *)
```

For whether the second argument `2` is sufficient for all your inputs, see [`FindTransientRepeat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindTransientRepeat.html).